# Are 2^n and n*2^n in the same time complexity?

Tags: algorithm, big-o, complexity-theory, time-complexity

Resources I've found on time complexity are unclear about when it is okay to ignore terms in a time complexity equation, specifically with non-polynomial examples.

It's clear to me that given something of the form n<sup>2</sup> + n + 1, the last two terms are insignificant.

Specifically, given two categorizations, 2<sup>n</sup>, and n*(2<sup>n</sup>), is the second in the same order as the first? Does the additional n multiplication there matter? Usually resources just say x<sup>n</sup> is in an exponential and grows much faster... then move on.

I can understand why it wouldn't since 2<sup>n</sup> will greatly outpace n, but because they're not being added together, it would matter greatly when comparing the two equations, in fact the difference between them will always be a factor of n, which seems important to say the least.

Comment: In my opinion, given that NLogN is regarded strictly slower than N, but most people don't really care by how much, it is safe to say N2^N is simply slower than 2^N, but not "slower enough" for people to care..

Comment: @tobias_k, I understand this point, but consider the example of O(n!). Would an extra n term really be different? O(n!) is to O(n*n!) as O(n!) is to O((n+1)!) aka the same graph simply shifted. The growth is the same though... In this case even though one is strictly large, is the growth different? isn't this what time complexity cares about?

Comment: @JackWu *but most people don't really care by how much* until you have to sort hundreds of millions of records with nlogn instead of n :)

Comment: In fact, `n! = o((n+1)!)`, that is, it grows strictly slower asymptotically.

Comment: Note that this has nothing to with complexity theory, it's "just" about aymptotics. Also, this kind of questions is probably better off on [cs.SE].

Comment: @C.B.: An algorithm which is O(N) but has a constant that's 30 times as large as one that's O(NlgN) will never significantly outperform the O(NlgN) algorithm for any plausible size of N.

Comment: Off topic, but doesn't stackoverflow support mathjax? I haven't learned that syntax yet, or I'd be editing up a storm...

Comment: You have to look at the graph, Jack Wu. O(n log n) grows faster than O(n) for large enough n AND larger values of n. But as we usually let the function represent time, or memory, use depending on number of element, we want them to be low.

Comment: @PatrickM No, MathJax isn't activated on [so] (it does work on, for example, [cs.se]).

Answer (score 238, accepted):

You will have to go to the formal definition of the big O (`O`) in order to answer this question.

The definition is that `f(x)` belongs to `O(g(x))` if and only if the limit `limsupx → ∞ (f(x)/g(x))` exists i.e. is not infinity. In short this means that there exists a constant `M`, such that value of `f(x)/g(x)` is never greater than `M`.

In the case of your question let `f(n) = n ⋅ 2n` and let `g(n) = 2n`. Then `f(n)/g(n)` is `n` which will still grow infinitely. Therefore `f(n)` does not belong to `O(g(n))`.

Comment: Yes, I should have remembered this. I guess I'm used to using limits for proving little o and normally am able to use my intuition to solve big O or big theta related questions. Well done sir!

Comment: For a slightly easier to read definition, see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Formal_definition)

Comment: Formally speaking, you can't take the limit of `O(f(x)/g(x))`; big-O notification is shorthand for a set of functions, not a single function whose value you can limit. However, I *think* it's true that you can show that `f(x) = O(g(x))` if `lim(x->infinity) f(x)/g(x)` exists.

Comment: Yeah I think you just need to remove that O

Comment: @chepner matty-d is right I just put `O` by error. Of course what I have written previously was nonsense. Also I **know** that f(x) belongs to O(g(x)) if lim(x->infinity) f(x)/g(x) exists. That is why I put it in my answer.

Comment: The limit does not have to exist; the ratio only has to be bounded above by a constant for sufficiently large x. For example, 2+sin(x) is in O(1), but (2+sin(x))/1 does not approach a limit as x->infinity.

Comment: The definition would be correct with `lim sup` instead of `lim`.

Comment: @user2357112 you are right of course. Initially I thought that using the compkete definition will make my answer more complicated and hard to understand, but I will fix the definition to be more precise. Great example btw.

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev please note that your in short description is incorrect. This must be true for a sufficiently large `x`, not for all values of `x`.

Comment: I incorporated David's and Steff's comments into the definition in the answer.

Comment: @SchighSchagh; What is this `sup` for ?

Comment: @K.Steff you are right of course. Still I will not incorporate this change in my answer, as it will almost never be important when we consider complexity functions. I want to keep the answer as comprehensive as possible. In all practical examples I can think of f(x)/g(x) will never be infinite (for positive x) and thus what I've written is accurate. I don't want to write `for sufficiently large x` as then I will have to explain what `sufficiently large` means and this will add a lot of complexity.

Comment: Some have pointed out that the limit `f(x)/g(x)` for `x to infty` need not exist, but `f(x)/g(x)` has to be bounded by some `M`. I'd like to add that the absolute value of `f(x)/g(x)` has to be considered. (Of course, in case of time complexity considerations both `f` and `g` are positive functions, so the absolute value is not necessary.)

Comment: @zaabson it is not true that this is the criteria that two complexity classes are different but even if it was, it is relatively straight forward to device an algorithm for a complexity. E.g. do something constant with all bitmasks of length n(2^n) or do something linear (to n) with these masks

Answer (score 90):

A quick way to see that `n⋅2ⁿ` is bigger is to make a change of variable. Let `m = 2ⁿ`. Then `n⋅2ⁿ = ( log₂m )⋅m` (taking the base-2 logarithm on both sides of `m = 2ⁿ` gives `n = log₂m` ), and you can easily show that `m log₂m` grows faster than `m`.

Comment: Thank you! This is the best answer in my opinion. Proofs based on formal definitions are correct, but if you have a stumbling block of some sort to get over, a very comfortable and familiar analogy will do the job the best and the fastest.

Comment: Stupid question, what is `lg`? Logarithm in base 2?

Comment: It's a lazy abbreviation. In computer science, it tends to mean base 2 because it mostly results from divide-and-conquer strategies. In big-O notation, it could represent anything, because the base-x logarithm of a number differs from its base-y logarithm by only a constant factor, regardless of x and y.

Comment: I should note in retrospect that `lg` is the ISO notation for a base-10 logarithm, rather than the base-agnostic use most commonly used when discussing asymptotic run times. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm#Particular_bases

Comment: Okay, sure, but I don't get why it's more obvious that m log m grows faster than m, than it is that n 2^n grows faster than 2^n.

Comment: I didn't say it was obvious, but working from the definition, you should be able to show that for any constant c, c*m <= m log m for large enough m. (Specifically, m > 2*c). Some people describe big-oh as ignoring lower-order terms, and by that informal definition, you might think that since n is lower order than 2^n, you can ignore it. (You can't, since it's a non-constant factor of the highest-order term, rather than a lower-order term as in, for example, 2^n + n).

Comment: This is so bad because the reduction doesnt yield any easier problem

Answer (score 10):

I agree that `n⋅2ⁿ` is not in `O(2ⁿ)`, but I thought it should be more explicit since the limit superior usage doesn't always hold.

By the formal definition of Big-O: `f(n)` is in `O(g(n))` if there exist constants `c > 0` and `n₀ ≥ 0` such that for all `n ≥ n₀` we have `f(n) ≤ c⋅g(n)`. It can easily be shown that no such constants exist for `f(n) = n⋅2ⁿ` and `g(n) = 2ⁿ`. However, it can be shown that `g(n)` is in `O(f(n))`.

In other words, `n⋅2ⁿ` is lower bounded by `2ⁿ`. This is intuitive. Although they are both exponential and thus are equally unlikely to be used in most practical circumstances, we cannot say they are of the same order because `2ⁿ` necessarily grows slower than `n⋅2ⁿ`.

Comment: `f(n) = 2*2^n` I think you meant `n*2^n`?

Answer (score 5):

I do not argue with other answers that say that `n⋅2ⁿ` grows faster than `2ⁿ`. But `n⋅2ⁿ` grows is still only exponential.

When we talk about algorithms, we often say that time complexity grows is exponential.
So, we consider to be `2ⁿ`, `3ⁿ`, `eⁿ`, `2.000001ⁿ`, or our `n⋅2ⁿ` to be same group of complexity with exponential grows.

To give it a bit mathematical sense, we consider a function `f(x)` to grow (not faster than) exponentially if exists such constant `c > 1`, that `f(x) = O(cx)`.

For `n⋅2ⁿ` the constant `c` can be any number greater than `2`, let's take `3`. Then:

`n⋅2ⁿ / 3ⁿ = n ⋅ (2/3)ⁿ` and this is less than `1` for any `n`.

So `2ⁿ` grows slower than `n⋅2ⁿ`, the last in turn grows slower than `2.000001ⁿ`. But all three of them grow exponentially.

Comment: In the last example, n*2^n is greater than 2.000001^n up to n = 34,726,000. At that point 2^n is a number with more than 10 million digits, so it doesn't really matter...

Comment: @gnasher729 It's just a constant which we may omit as f(n) and c*f(n) is same complexity in terms of big-O. e.g. 40'000'000*2.000001^n is greater than n*2^n right away. But you are right, it does not really matter, I would say it does not really matter once we hit exponential grows (unless we get only small values of n).

Answer (score 2):

You asked "is the second in the same order as the first? Does the additional n multiplication there matter?" These are two different questions with two different answers.

n 2^n grows asymptotically faster than 2^n. That's that question answered.

But you could ask "if algorithm A takes 2^n nanoseconds, and algorithm B takes n 2^n nanoseconds, what is the biggest n where I can find a solution in a second / minute / hour / day / month / year? And the answers are n = 29/35/41/46/51/54 vs. 25/30/36/40/45/49. Not much difference in practice.

The size of the biggest problem that can be solved in time T is O (ln T) in both cases.

Answer (score 0):

Very Simple answer is 'NO'

see `2^n`  and `n.2^n`

as seen `n.2^n > 2^n`  for any `n>0`

or you can even do it by applying log on both sides then you get

```
 n.log(2)    <    n.log(2) + log(n)
```

hence by both type of analysis that is by

1. substituting a number
2. using log

we see that `n.2^n`  is greater than `2^n` as visibly seen

so if you get a equation like

`O ( 2^n + n.2^n )`  which can be replaced as `O ( n.2^n)`